# Iterating multimap with conditional statement

Tags: c++, c++98

First of all, I'm using **C++98/03**

I'm iterating my multimap starting from the second element:

```
multimap<pair<string, string>, pair<string, int> >::iterator it = paths.begin();
it++;
```

I have a conditional statement: if first element of first pair in current iterator is equal to the first element of first pair in a previous iterator, then do something, eg. print these elements.

```
for(; it != paths.end(); it++) {
    if((*it).first.first == (*it--).first.first ) {
        it++;
        cout << (*it).first.first << " ";
        cout << (*it--).first.first << endl;
        it++;
    }
    else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

My question is how can I use a copy of an iterator instead of incrementing it back after every (*it--)?

Comment: `multimap<pair<string, string>, pair<string, int> >::iterator another_iterator = it`?

Comment: if you can swap the order of the two outputs you could simply first print `it`, then increment and only then print `it` again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use another iterator:

```
 typedef multimap<pair<string, string>, pair<string, int> >::iterator iterator;
 for( iterator it = paths.begin(); it != paths.end(); ) {
     iterator prev = it++;
     if( it == paths.end() )
         break;
     if( prev->first.first == it->first.first ) {
         // output here
     }
 }
```

Note your code is incorrect, first of all it has UB as `==` is not sequenced. But even if you use different iterator on the left side, you would get wrong behaviour:

```
 iterator it1 = it;
 if((*it1).first.first == (*it--).first.first ) { // not UB anymore, but result is always true as you compare the same element
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an utility similar to C++11's [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
T prev(T it)
{
    std::advance(it, -1);
    return it;
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
for(; it != paths.end(); it++) {
    if((*it).first.first == prev(it)->first.first ) {
        cout << (*it).first.first << " ";
        cout << prev(it)->first.first << endl;
    }
    else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @OP you should also consider protecting the code from the corner cases like `paths.size() == 1`